# using React Native prop onBackButtonPress?: () => void

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-props

What is the correct chain of actions to use my prop `onBackButtonPress?: () => void;` ?
Right now typescript shows an error for the onPress -

```
Type '(() => void) | undefined' is not assignable to type '() => void'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '() => void'.
```

Do i need to type something completely different for the prop in my IconButton and app.tsx Header ?

```
type HeaderProps = {
    onBackButtonPress?: () => void;
};

export function Header({ onBackButtonPress }}: HeaderProps) {
    return (
            <View>
              <IconButton onPress={onBackButtonPress} />
            </View>
    );
}
```

app.tsx file

```
 <Header onBackButtonPress={() => null} />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the `onPress` prop of `IconButton` needs to receive the type `() => void`. However, `onBackButtonPress` is marked as optional, thus it could be `undefined`. These two types do not match.

In order to fix this, either allow `onPress` in `IconButton` to receive `undefined` or provide a dummy function if `onBackButtonpress` is `undefined` or do not mark `onBackButtonPress` as optional.

**Not marked as optional**

```js
type HeaderProps = {
    onBackButtonPress: () => void;
};
```

In this case, the `Header` component cannot receive an undefined object for `onBackButtonPress`.

**Create dummy function**

```js
onPress={onBackButtonPress ? onBackButtonPress : () => {}} />
```

This will just do nothing onPress if `onBackButtonPress` is undefined.

**Change the type of `IconButton`**

```js
type IconButtonProps = {
    onPress?: () => void
}

export IconButton(props: IconButtonProps) {
   ...
}
```